# How do I determine the screen resolution of an application in Xorg?

Tags: xorg

I do not want to know the resolution of my monitor. I would like to know the resolution of a fullscreen window running within Xorg.

For example, the resolution of Firefox when I maximise the window. This is different to the screen resolution because of the task bar. I need this so I can set a resolution for Wine's virtual desktop.

The `xprop` command surprisingly does not provide this. Are there any other commands I could use to determine this. Keep in mind, it can be any window.

Comment: The resolution of a fullscreen window *is* the resolution of the monitor. If your screen is split among multiple outputs/monitors, making a window full-screen will make the size of a single monitor by default. You can get all the data with `xrandr` -- including panning and size of the whole screen. It's not at all "surprising" that `xprop` didn't provide that info; xprop is used to set or get the X11 "properties" (chunks of data attached to windows).

Comment: xprop give you some informations : take a look at _NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) and _NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION(CARDINAL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few different options. However, I believe `wmctrl` will give you the best results. As pointed out by user dirkt this tool is dependent on your Window Manager supporting it.

```
wmctrl -lG | grep [Name of Application]
```

Will give you the x,y offsets, width and height in pixels of a given application. I got the answer from [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27894/get-window-size-in-shell).

You should also look into the output of `xdpyinfo` and `xwininfo`. These are tools for X server that can tell you various points of information about a given X window or application. Doing something like the following will give you highly accurate information about your display:

```
xdpyinfo | more
```

You then want to scroll down to screen #0 and you get all of the details from screen size in pixels to dpi, etc. Very accurate to your current X settings.

Additionally there is `xwininfo`. This will tell you statistics of a given window application too.

There is also [this Unix and Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/how-do-i-find-the-window-dimensions-and-position-accurately-including-decoration/) that is relevant to this post. They use additional scripts but you can get relatively accurate information using `xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry`.

You report that you are going to be using applications in full screen. As user mosvy points out, your `xrandr` output of your screen will be the exact dimensions of your monitor and thus any full screen application.

Comment: You should mention that `wmctrl` interrogates the window manager (hence WM). There are ways to determine screen resolution (`xdpinfo`, `xrandr`) that don't depend on a WM supporting `wmctrl`, nor do they depend on the application being maximized at the time you do the interrogation.

Comment: @dirkt from what I gathered ToffeeYogurtPots just wants to know the resolution that an application takes up but not the output from `xrandr`. I can expand this answer to include that information though. Thank you.